# Trying to locate source of a story about Japanese storyteller's apprentice who is mistaken for a master

Tags: identification-request, japanese-language

I'm trying to locate the source of a story I remember, for an essay I'm writing. Not sure if the story is fact, fiction, or legend. It concerns an apprentice to a master storyteller in Japan (Rakugo I think). The master makes the apprentice practice the same bit of the same story over and over, never lets him try anything else. Frustrated, the apprentice runs away, and comes across an inn where he's asked to tell a story for his supper. Of course, he tells the only one he knows. Everyone's in awe of his skills, and say they didn't realise he was a master of the art. Realising why his master has been making him do this, he returns to his master and becomes a master in his own right.